# Efficient Query - When querying a specific group of IDs in Table A, how can I check a condition in Table B for selected id in Table A?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization, query-optimization

I have a table of users: `| username |`

I have a table of relationships: `| follower | following |`

Currently, I have a query: `SELECT username FROM user WHERE username IN ('A', 'B', ...)`

Now when I perform the above query, I want to check if each user is being followed by the current user and somehow indicate it in another column of the result. Like this: `SELECT username, is_followed FROM user WHERE username IN ('A', 'B', ...) AND "is_followed is true when username is being followed by 'CURRENT_USERNAME'"`

Is there any efficient way of doing this without a foreach loop or subqueries?

Any answer would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you want from your description. This query gives all the selceted users and a flag to say whether they are followed or not. If you just want the users that are followed by the current user then change `left outer join` to `inner join`

```
Select
    u.username,
    case when r.following is null then 0 else 1 end is_followed
From
    user u
        left outer join
    relationship r
        on u.username = r.following and r.follower = 'CURRENT_USERNAME'
Where
    u.username in ('A', 'B', ...)
```

This assumes there are no duplicates in the relationship table.

Answer (score 0):

this one gives the result as you explained.

```
    SELECT  username
            ,Case   When q2.username IS NULL 
                    Then 0 
                    Else 1 
            END 
            As is_followed
    FROM user q1
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        select Distinct following as username
        from relationships
        where follower = 'CURRENT_USERNAME'
    )q2
    on q1.username=q2.username
    WHERE q1.username IN ('A', 'B', ...)
```